# Expire data in Azure Table storage without creating a hot key

Tags: data-modeling, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to model Azure Table storage for a simple website that works like so:

- Visitors can create a "widget"
- Visitors work with one widget and all its associated data together
- Widgets expire after some period of time and should be deleted from the table

I'd like to use a single table for this app, but I'm not sure how to model expiration without either (a) scanning the whole table, or (b) creating a hot key. [DynamoDB has TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) that would help, but I haven't seen a similar feature for Azure Table storage.

This is my current design:

| PartitionKey | RowKey | Other fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| widget:1 | self | { expires_at: 1000010 } |
| widget:1 | associated:1 | ... |
| widget:1 | associated:2 | ... |
| widget:2 | self | { expires_at: 1000020 } |
| widget:2 | associated:1 | ... |
| expires | timestamp:1000010 | { PK: "widget:1" } |
| expires | timestamp:1000020 | { PK: "widget:2" } |

This makes querying a widget by ID easy because I can simply use the filter `PartitionKey eq 'widget:1'` to get everything for widget 1.

However, the partition key "expires" becomes a hot key. To find expired widgets, I'd do `PK eq 'expires' and RowKey lt 'timestamp:(expiry_threshold)'`. For simplicity, I was planning to run the "expire old widgets" routine on every request to the website, so every request would hit the partition that contains "expires".

This app's traffic is very low so this won't be a problem in practice, but I'm wondering if there's a "better" design I'm not thinking of, or if this kind of design is common and necessary.

Comment: You can take a look at Cosmos DB SQL API (which is more like DynamoDB). That has TTL capabilities and will auto-delete documents based on the TTL settings.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm sure that's a good solution for a production system that would be earning me money, but this is an exercise for me to learn more about data modeling with table storage. Also, a quick look at the pricing calculator tells me CosmosDB would be around $23 /month while table storage would be pennies.

Comment: (After another look, there is an always-free tier of CosmosDB that would work, but I'm still interested in knowing if there's a better practice for table storage)

Comment: Cosmos DB is expensive! Azure Table Storage doesn’t has TTL feature. You would need to roll out your own solution.